# Multiple ajax requests, session not recognized?

Tags: php, ajax, session

In my `'index.php'`, I make two ajax requests inside `$(document).ready()`. The requests are sent to the same php file `'process.php'`.

At the beginning of `'index.php'`, I have something like:

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
$_SESSION['someVar'] = "someVal";
```

Then I have the two ajax calls.
For these two requests, `'process.php'` must use `$_SESSION['someVar']`.
The code in `'process.php'` looks something like:

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
doSomethingWith($_SESSION['someVar']);
```

When I load `'index.php'`, I can see two session files in my session folder: the older contains `someVar`, and the newer doesn't. When I cancel one ajax call, I have only one session file that contains `someVar`. That means my session is not recognized in `'process.php'` for the second ajax call, so a new session is created and the old one is lost.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're using `session_regenerate_id()` in this context? This updates the current session id with a newly generated one, so it is rather expected you see more than one session after calling it a few times.

Comment: I do this for security reasons. I know it updates the session id, but it should not create a new distinct session, just change the id, right?

Comment: Are these two AJAX requests run in the same time?